# problem in writing a simple service and client(python)

Tags: ros, rospy, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I type

```
rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
```

it displays

```
from: can't read /var/mail/beginner_tutorials.srv
/home/exbot/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 4: import: command not found
/home/exbot/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/exbot/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py: line 6: ` def handle_add_two_ints(req):'
```

how can I solve this question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217796/problem-in-writing-a-simple-service-and-client(python)/) by [ZouQiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/23923/zouqiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the script is being executed by the shell and not by python.
Does your script start with a shebang?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This is required to be recognized as a python node.

Actually, there a quick google turned up mutiple questions about the same thing here on ROS answers
http://answers.ros.org/question/164091/rosrun-of-a-working-python-script-fails/
http://answers.ros.org/question/149916/problems-with-rostutorials-writingserviceclientpython/

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2017-03-24**:
This is exactly the case. I had this kind of response because I had (accidentally) included a space in front of `#!/usr/bin/env python`